The type or namespace name 'Schema' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations' not working on another machine
Copied code from one machine to another and now it won't compile on new machine. Getting error:
Error is on this line
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

Error
The type or namespace name 'Schema' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations'

The code is targeting .Net 4.0 and is working on old machine. .Net Framework 4.8 is installed on both machines.
Both codes reference this DLL from same location which is:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll

Please tell me what could be the issue?

The code is targeting .Net 4.0 that's the problem. .NET Framework 4.0 went out of support along with Windows XP in 2016. It was already replaced by 4.5 back in 2012. The Schema namespace doesn't exist in 4.0. Targeting 4.0, if at all possible, only causes problems. The oldest supported .NET Framework is 4.6.2. The solution is to target a valid version instead of 4.0

Besides, if 4.8 is installed on the target machine you're not using 4.0 at all. All 4.x runtimes are binary replacements. Installing a newer version replaces the previous one. That means your application already runs on 4.8

@PanagiotisKanavos Then why is it working on old machine? Both machines have Windows 2019.

Windows 2019 isn't old and never allowed 4.0 to run. It came with 4.7.2 out of the box, so you never really worked with 4.0. What you got is a compilation error. It's quite possible the project on the "old" machine doesn't target 4.0. Or due to a fluke, a local copy of the assembly was loaded. You can't depend on flukes. System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema was added in 4.5 so it's invisible in 4.0

Is there any valid reason you're trying to target a runtime that doesn't exist on your servers, while trying to use code that requires a newer one?

Thanks. I will accept your answer. Please post so I can accept it.
